# Is it possible to downgrade gcc 4.6.3 to 4.6.1?

Tags: gcc

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS.
I installed gcc 4.6.1 from tar.gz , but when I check version with `gcc --version` the output version is gcc 4.6.3. Is there any way to make the version to become 4.6.1?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide the exact steps that you used to compile GCC, as well as the source of the source (pun completely intended)?

Comment: I do it exactly like [this site](http://buildall.wordpress.com/tag/gcc-4-6/) with addition like installing `gcc-multilib` `g++-multilib`. Then I added 
`export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`
`export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu`
`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` in .bashrc. I added it because of some error.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been a mismarked download try this one:

http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.6.1/

Comment: After that try gcc --version if you still get the wrong version it could be an error with there release. Is there a specific reason you need 4.6.1?

Comment: This is, generally, a *bad* idea.  If you want to download anything that you are going to be running on your computer (or, in this case, compiling and then running), then you should always use the official sources *first*, no matter how trustworthy the site may be.  In this case, then that source is [the "Releases" page on the GCC homepage](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html).  Also, [check out the WOT scorecard for that particular site...](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/netgull.com?utm_source=addon&utm_content=contextmenu).

Comment: @KalebM. Okay I'll try it. The reason I need 4.6.1 is because my miniPC uses gcc 4.6.1 and if I use another version in my laptop, there will be possibilities of compilation error. If I install newest gcc on my miniPC, it will make its performance slower. (That's what my senior said actually)

Comment: @InkBlend My first tar.gz was downloaded from that site before

Comment: @micmec, which site?  The official GCC page, or this link that Kaleb M. posted?

Comment: Official GCC page. I have tried the link that Kaleb M. posted too but still resulting 4.6.3. Is it really take effect if I use 4.6.3 although the miniPC has 4.6.1?

Comment: @micmec, good, I just just warning you about downloading, compiling, or executing (or, Linus forbid, all three) code from a third party site.  Anyway, are you *sure* that you need 4.6.1?  If you do, I can try to help, but I would recommend using the official packages unless you specifically need an older version.  Performance should be relatively close except in certain situations.